# Yii2 : File Input throws error after submitting form

Tags: php, yii2, active-form

When I click on the Signup button I receive the following error: Array to string conversion.
I think that the error occurs when I call `fileInput()` method but i don't know how to solve it.
This is the partial code of the view

```
<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(); ?>
<?= $form->field($model, 'username')->textInput(['autofocus' => true]) ?>

<?= $form->field($model, 'password')->passwordInput() ?>

<?= $form->field($model, 'email') ?>


<?= $form->field($modelUpload, 'imageFile')->fileInput() ?>

<div class="form-group">
    <?= Html::submitButton('Signup', ['class' => 'btn', 'name' => 'signup-button']) ?>
</div>
<?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
```

While this is the code for the controller:

```
    <?php

class SiteController extends Controller {

    /**
     * Signs user up.
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function actionSignup() {
        $model = new SignupForm();
        $modelUpload = new UploadForm();
        if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $modelUpload->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {
            $modelUpload->imageFile = UploadedFile::getInstances($modelUpload, 'imageFile');

            if ($user = $model->signup()) {

                if (Yii::$app->getUser()->login($user) && $modelUpload->upload()) {

                    return $this->goHome();
                }
            }
        }

        return $this->render('signup', [
                    'model' => $model,
                    'modelUpload' => $modelUpload,
        ]);
    }

}
```

This is the code of the model. It's the same of the official documentation.

```
<?php

class UploadForm extends Model {

    /**
     * @var UploadedFile
     */
    public $imageFile;

    public function rules() {
        return [
            [['imageFile'], 'file', 'skipOnEmpty' => false, 'extensions' => 'png, jpg'],
        ];
    }

    public function upload() {
        if ($this->validate()) {
            $this->imageFile->saveAs('uploads/' . $this->imageFile->baseName . '.' . $this->imageFile->extension);
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

}
?>
```

Errors:

[image: First screenshot]

[image: Second screenshot]

[image: Third screenshot]

Comment: Please add the specific error.

Comment: you should add the stack trace properly the source code where the line is specified is not required the full stack trace should be added see [**`HERE`**](https://imgur.com/a/inzkF)

Comment: this is strange does it work when you remove the `fileInput` from the form, and what version are you on `Yii2` ?

Comment: one thing does this error occur when submitting a form or loading the form for the first time?

Comment: it occurs after submitting

Comment: it works without fileInput. @MuhammadOmerAslam

Comment: added an answer see below it will be fixed, do mark the answer as correct if it works for you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### `Instant Solution`

Change your line inside the `actionSignup()` from below

```
UploadedFile::getInstances($modelUpload, 'imageFile');
```

to

```
UploadedFile::getInstance($modelUpload, 'imageFile');
```

### `Reason`

It's only a single file you are uploading not multiple files so `getInstances()` should be `getInstance()`

### `About`

> `getInstance` : Returns an uploaded file for the given model
>   attribute. The file should be uploaded using
>   [[\yii\widgets\ActiveField::fileInput()]]
>
> `getInstances`:  Returns all uploaded files for the given model
>   attribute.

Comment: I love you too @Yosirion 

Answer (score 1):

if you want to upload **multiple** files - having`'maxFiles' > 1` in your model's `FileValidator` rules - change your **attribute name** from:

```
<?= $form->field($modelUpload, 'imageFile')->fileInput() ?>
```

to

```
<?= $form->field($modelUpload, 'imageFile[]')->fileInput() ?>
```

read this:
https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/input-file-upload#uploading-multiple-files